# Cloud Firestore error when getting data error: argument type mismatch

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using dart SDK >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 before using this version there was no trouble with the code below but now I'm getting an error, how can I fix that? Or is it related to the Equatable package I'm using?

**Getting Data**

```
import 'package:bloc_todo2/data/models/todo.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FirebaseTodoRepository {
  var todoPath = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos');

  Future<List<Todo>> getTodo() async {
    List<Todo> todoList = [];
    var response = await todoPath.get();
    response.docs.forEach((element) {
      todoList.add(Todo.fromMap(element.data())); // this line gives ERROR 
    });
    return todoList;
  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

**MODEL fromMap Method**

```
 factory Todo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Todo(
      complete: map['complete'],
      text: map['text'],
      id: map['id'],
      colorHex: map['colorHex'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

`factory Todo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>? map)`

It makes your map nullable.

Or adding `!` to you're declared variables, to tell dart that they won't be null.

Comment: still same unfortunately

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firestore dependancy?

Comment: yes im using 1.03 for firestore and 1.0.2 for core

Comment: after adding ! to declared variables it's working. thanks.